# PHP: How do I search in an unindexed array?

Tags: php, search, arrays, indexing

I have an array that is formatted like so (this example has 5 keys):

```
[0]: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[1]: Date: Wed, 10 Feb 2010 12:16:24 GMT
[2]: Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
[3]: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.6
[4]: etc..
```

The array keys sometimes alternate, as one may be omitted. How can I search for the array with "Server: ..." in it, and if it exists display it?

For the life of me I am confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 foreach($your_array as $value)
 {
  if (stripos($value, 'Server:') !== false)
  {
    echo $value;  // we found it !!
    break;
  }
 }
```

Comment: What if `Server:` is not at the start of the string?

Comment: @Gumbo: it will still be found, i am using stripos, it find it where ever it is.

Comment: @Gumbo: strpos function gives the location of the string whereever it is found, you know that :)

Comment: @Sarfraz: Yes, and that’s the point. The asker probably just wants to print the value if it starts with `Server:`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for actually, It only can contain one string of 'Server:' and worked flawlessly. Thanks Sarfraz.

Answer (score 3):

The intuitive approach would be to iterate the array and test each item:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (strncasecmp(substr($item, 0, 7), 'Server:') === 0) {
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

[`array_search()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) — *Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful*

You have to be a bit more specific about whether you want to search for a substring or an exact value, e.g. you want to search for *"Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)"* or just anything with the substring *"Server"* in it. In the latter case, go with [Gumbo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236720/php-how-do-i-search-in-an-unindexed-array/2236735#2236735), as `array_search` cannot be used for substring searches.